# how to deobfuscate to java zkm?

Tags: java, jar

I will have a question for you, dear forum residents. I have a .jar file encrypted with ZKM which I think will work for me. I don't know how to decrypt this, can you help me?

Comment: ZKM (Zelix KlassMaster) by default obfuscates code, not encrypts it (exception: strings). Therefore there is no decryption. The names that have been obfuscated are gone unless ZKM forgot some identifier which can be used to reconstruct the original class name (but I don't think that the ZKM authors made such a mistake).

Comment: So we can't remove it from this software?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not related to reverse-engineering.

Comment: I also vote to close this question. In case the OP wanted to know how to decompile the JAR file, I suggest http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/ with obfuscation mapping files.

Comment: I don't agree with closing the issue. OP made a grammatical mistake, using _"decrypt"_ instead of _"deobfuscate"_. There clearly exist solutions for this sort of problem and I don't see how this could possibly be justified for closure under the premise of _"not related to reverse-engineering"_ aside from the lack of awareness of the subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few open source tools that make removing obfuscation patterns quite easy. Some have explicit support for ZKM. Here are are the two popular ones:

- https://github.com/java-deobfuscator/deobfuscator
- https://github.com/GraxCode/threadtear

And here is one specifically for android:

- https://github.com/CalebFenton/simplify